# Export list to Excel - 50'000 limit

Tags: excel, export, list-item

We have a user that has a SP2013 list with nearly 100'000 items.

In a previous SP2007 environment, they could export the entire list to excel. In SP2013, they are hitting a hard limit in Excel of 52'000 items.

The list threshold settings are set at 5'000 and 20'000 for admins, and changing these does not affect the export to excel.

Is there a setting somewhere that I can change to allow this data connection to work like it used to in SP2007?

Answer (score 0):

you could view in QUICK VIEW – or “edit the list” and while in this view, copy and paste the data to Excel; of course you would need to watch for the right fields being shown in your view, and no limitations of numbers of items being displayed.

Comment: Thanks, however that isn't an ideal solution for the end user.

Comment: Sorry but i misunderstood the question.

Comment: It's ok, I found out that it's the resource throttling settings that need to be changed on the web application. All fine now.